# How to use Crosstab

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does anyone knows whether can Crosstab function be used on a table with multiple columns?

```
Date│ Event_1│ Hours_1│ Event_2│ Hours_2│ Event_3│ Hours_3│
```

Into

```
Date│ Event_1│ Hours_1│
Date│ Event_2│ Hours 2│
Date│ Event_3│ Hours 3│
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have to "normalize" your data in a format crosstab function can accept, eg:

```
with normalized as (
    select date, 1 as num, 'event' as key, event_1 as value from tabl
    union all 
    select date, 2 as num, 'event' as key, event_2 as value from tabl
    union all 
    select date, 3 as num, 'event' as key, event_3 as value from tabl
    union all
    select date, 1 as num, 'hours' as key, hours_1 as value from tabl
    union all 
    select date, 2 as num, 'hours' as key, hours_2 as value from tabl
    union all 
    select date, 3 as num, 'hours' as key, hours_3 as value from tabl
)
select date, key, value from normalized order by num;
```